# Error when instancing meshes using Context, in a Gatsby app using React Three Fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, gatsby, react-three-fiber

In my gatsby app, I'm trying to make use of instances to show a mesh multiple times. For this, I'm using the following code by https://gltf.pmnd.rs/:

```
import React, { useRef, useMemo, useContext, createContext } from "react"
import { useGLTF, Merged } from "@react-three/drei"
import plank from "./planks.gltf"

const context = createContext()
export function Instances({ children, ...props }) {
  const { nodes } = useGLTF(plank)
  const instances = useMemo(
    () => ({
      PlankStyle: nodes.PlankStyle02029,
    }),
    [nodes]
  )
  return (
    <Merged meshes={instances} {...props}>
      {instances => <context.Provider value={instances} children={children} />}
    </Merged>
  )
}

export function Planks(props) {
  const instances = useContext(context)
  console.log(instances)
  return (
    <group {...props} dispose={null}>
      <instances.PlankStyle
        position={[-3.088, -0.01, 5.742]}
        rotation={[0, Math.PI / 2, 0]}
        scale={[1, 0.947, 1]}
      />
      <instances.PlankStyle
        position={[-3.088, -0.01, 6.752]}
        rotation={[0, Math.PI / 2, 0]}
        scale={[1, 0.947, 1]}
      />
      <instances.PlankStyle
        position={[-3.088, -0.01, 7.518]}
        rotation={[0, Math.PI / 2, 0]}
        scale={[1, 0.947, 1]}
      />
    </group>
  )
}

useGLTF.preload(plank)
```

I then load this component on my indexpage like so:

```
...
const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
      <Canvas shadows dpr={[1, 1.5]} camera={{ position: [-1.5, 1, 5.5], fov: 45, near: 1, far: 20}}>
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <Planks />
        </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

This throws an error and when I log `instances` it is undefined so I'm thinking it's gotta be something with the context. Given that it's Gatsby I feel like there is some kinda extra hoop I gotta jump through to get it working, just can't figure out what that is.

I looked into using context in gatsby and came across various guides on how to wrap the whole app in a context provider. I gave that a shot like so:

```
export const AppContext = createContext()

export const AppProvider = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const { nodes } = useGLTF(plank)

  const instances = useMemo(
    () => ({
      PlankStyle: nodes.PlankStyle02029,
    }),
    [nodes]
  )

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        instances,
      }}
    >
      <Merged meshes={instances} {...props}>
        {instances => (
          <AppContext.Provider value={instances} children={children} />
        )}
      </Merged>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

and `instances` was indeed defined. However when I tried to load it into my Canvas, I got this error `R3F: Hooks can only be used within the Canvas component!` Tried wrapping that part in a Canvas but then it just went bonkers with errors plus I need to be able to put this into an existing canvas with other elements anyways.

Given that these models are page specific , I'd like to figure out how to get it working more in line with the first snippet of code posted above.

At this point though, I'm open to any suggestions as I can't think of anything else (other than manually copying over the positions to duplicated meshes which I'd like to avoid)

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get it working without context. At least now I can pretty much copy all the instances from https://gltf.pmnd.rs/ without manually adding positions n stuff. Good enough for now I guess but still grateful for any suggestions.

```
import React, { useRef, useMemo, useContext, createContext } from "react"
import { useGLTF, Merged } from "@react-three/drei"
import plank from "./planks.gltf"

export function Planks() {
  const { nodes } = useGLTF(plank)
  const instances = useMemo(
    () => ({
      PlankStyle: nodes.PlankStyle02029,
    }),
    [nodes]
  )
  return (
    <Merged meshes={instances}>
      {({ PlankStyle }) => (
        <>
          <group dispose={null}>
            <PlankStyle
              position={[-3.088, -0.01, 5.742]}
              rotation={[0, Math.PI / 2, 0]}
              scale={[1, 0.947, 1]}
            />
            <PlankStyle
              position={[-3.088, -0.01, 6.752]}
              rotation={[0, Math.PI / 2, 0]}
              scale={[1, 0.947, 1]}
            />
            <PlankStyle
              position={[-3.088, -0.01, 7.518]}
              rotation={[0, Math.PI / 2, 0]}
              scale={[1, 0.947, 1]}
            />
          </group>
        </>
      )}
    </Merged>
  )
}

useGLTF.preload(plank)
```